# How to bind image source to an observable inside an ngFor loop?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, src

I am trying to display an image inside an ngFor loop like this :

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let leg of flight.route">
   <img [src]="getImage(leg.airline) | async" />
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 getImage(airlineCode: string): Observable<any> {
     return this.companyLogoService.getLogo(airlineCode);
 }
```

This doesn't work. When this gets executed, all the requests to `getImage()` seem to interrupt each other and loop infinitely :

[image]

According to [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612566/6114088), a way to handle this is to manually create a template variable holding the observable and then to pass this variable to the `[src]` tag, but I can't afford to to that because of the ngFor loop.

How can I bind this image source properly ?

**EDIT:**

The requests to `getImage()` were not interrupting each other. This behavior was caused by Angular change detection who went crazy because I directly mapped a function call to `[src]`, which is not supported. The same problem happened with a single image to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is apparently no such way to make this binding happen, I used an array to hold my observables, and I mapped them by index in my template.

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'flight-card',
  templateUrl: './flight-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flight-card.component.scss']
})
export class FlightCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public flight: Flight;

  public airlineImages: Observable<any>[];

  constructor(private companyLogoService: CompanyLogoService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.airlineImages = [];
    this.flight.route.forEach(leg => {
      this.airlineImages.push(this.companyLogoService.getLogo(leg.airline));
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let leg of flight.route; let i = index">
   <img [src]="this.airlineImages[i] | async" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is not a good approach as change detection run quite often, and with each change detection 'getImage' is going to be invoked.

You can try to get all images on initialization and populate it on your template

```
getFlights() { 
    this.flights = /*code to get flights*/;

    // after you have retrieved flights
    this.flights.forEach((flight, index) => { 
    readImageFile(index, flight.airline);
    });
}

getImage(index: number, airlineCode: string) {
    this.companyLogoService.getLogo(airlineCode)
        .subscribe((result) => {
            // result depends on your server i.e. base64 data, image url etc
            this.flights[index].img = result;
        });
}

<div *ngFor="let flight of flights | async;">
    <img [src]="flight.img">
</div>
```

Comment: This is kind of what I ended up doing, but I kept the images appart from the component input data

Comment: You can create a separate array for images, but I'd strongly recommend to run such codes only once, as in such cases change detection can affect the application performance very heavily

Comment: I think it's fine because I am now referring to a variable (an array of observables) instead of a function. This array is populated when the component is initiated, then it won't ever change.

Answer (score 0):

Do that using `components`.

Here is working [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I don't understand how your answer is related to my question

Comment: i have write sample component to undestand your issue ,you dont want to insert it to array

Comment: can you give sample api i will map it

Answer (score 0):

As described the **change detection** leads to this behavior, it will invoke the method each time and will trigger the method (a http request).

A working approach would be, loading your image(s) at initialization of your component. (Important, add a *ngIf to your component, otherwise your object will probably not be initialized)

#1 Parent component

```
<ns-bills-cardview *ngIf="billsBook" [billsBook]="billsBook"></ns-bills-cardview>
```

#2 Inside your component, just load your images from cache or http request

```
export class BillsCardviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() billsBook: BillsBook[];
  productDocuments: BillBookPrictureData[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.userTake1Observable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        // pre-loading billBook detail images
        this.loadingImages();
      }
    });
  }

  onLoadImage(productUUID): string {
    const picture: BillBookPrictureData = this.productDocuments.find(
      productDocument => productDocument.key === productUUID
    );

    return picture.data;
  }

  onItemTap(bill: BillsBook, productUUID: string) {
    this.billDetailDialogModalService.openBillDetailDialogModal(this.vcRef, this.modal, bill.uuid, productUUID);
  }

  /**
   * This method will get called to re-load all billBook images
   */
  private loadingImages() {
    this.billsBook.forEach(bill => {
      const billUUID = bill.uuid;
      bill.products.forEach(product => {
        const billBookPicture: BillBookPrictureData = { key: null, data: null };

        // cache billPictureData
        billBookPicture.key = product.productDocument.uuid;
        billBookPicture.data = this.loadImage(billUUID, billBookPicture.key);
        this.productDocuments.push(billBookPicture);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * This method will load all images from appSettings or send http request
   * @param string billUUID
   * @param string productUUID
   */
  private loadImage(billUUID: string, productUUID: string): string {
    //load billBook images from cache
    if (this.appSettingsService.hasBillDetailFileData(billUUID, productUUID)) {
      return this.appSettingsService.getBillDetailFileData(billUUID, productUUID);
    }

    //load billBook images via http request
    this.documentControllerService
      .getDocumentFileDataUsingGET(productUUID)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        fileData => {
          //store image in cache
          this.appSettingsService.setBillDetailFileData(fileData, billUUID, productUUID);

          //push loaded image to productDocument array
          const billBookPicture: BillBookPrictureData = { key: productUUID, data: fileData };
          this.productDocuments.push(billBookPicture);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
}
```

#3 Mask

```
  <StackLayout *ngFor="let product of item.products" (tap)="onItemTap(item, product.uuid)">
     <Image
     *ngIf="productDocuments"
     [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + onLoadImage(product.productDocument.uuid)"
     [alt]="product.name"
     width="200"
     height="120"
     stretch="aspectFill"
     ></Image>
     .
     . 
     .
  </StackLayout>
```

This solution can be adapted to load one image or multiple.